# There exists finitely many numbers s.t.: "the number of digits = total number of its prime divisor"

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that there exists finitely many numbers $n$ satisfying:

"the number of digits" $=$ total number of its prime divisor"

For instance, $18 = 3^2*2$ satisfies, while $27 = 3^3$ does not.

Comment: There are few primes less than 10...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main idea is that the primorial $n\#$ grows much faster than the powers of $10$. If you have a number $x$ which is a product of $n$ distinct primes, then it is *at least* as large as the product of the *first* $n$ primes.

If a number is a product of $11$ or more distinct prime factors, then it is *at least* $12$ digits long because $31\# = 200560490130$ ($31$ is the $11$th prime) is twelve digits long. Therefore any number which satisfies your criteria must be less than $10$ digits long and the set of such numbers is finite.